# Improved power factor symbol [pf]

Tags: math-mode, spacing, symbols

I am currently using `\newcommand\pf{\ensuremath{\mathrm{p{\!}f}}` to typeset the power factor abbreviation but would like the `p` and `f` to appear closer together.  They can even touch in this application to ensure that do not appear as two separate variables in equations.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you have a reference on how it is supposed to look?

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner That is a very good question.  IEC now prescribes the symbol `$\lambda$`.  - see (https://www.electropedia.org/iev/iev.nsf/display?openform&ievref=131-11-46)

Comment: A suggestion: forget having heard anything about `\ensuremath`.

Comment: @egreg What is the best replacement for `\ensuremath`?

Comment: `\(a+b\)` is the correct way to input a math formula. Or `$a+b$`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareMathOperator{\pf}{p\mspace{-2.75mu}f}

\begin{document}

$\pf(x)$

\end{document}
```

Of course, different fonts might require different negative spacing.

[image]

Comment: It looks like the OP has determined in the meantime that he/she should be using the symbol `$\lambda$`...

Comment: @Mico correct.  The answer above is also very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

IEC 60050 now prescribes the symbol `\lambda` as the correct symbol. - see https://www.electropedia.org/iev/iev.nsf/display?openform&ievref=131-11-46

Comment: I would recommend to put this ad a remark in the question and delete it as a separate answer.

Comment: I think a comment is not salient enough.  It is important to use the correct symbol for power factor. @Dr.ManuelKuehner I am willing to delete my answer if you post it, as your question lead to the correct answer.

Comment: I do not want to take away the accepted answer from egreg :).

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner  I will retain my acceptance of his answer :)